# Time series as input for CNN using the channels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series, conv-neural-network

Does it make sense to use the channels in the Input of a CNN as a way to input a time-series?
For example I have five time-series, each one containing three 10x10 picures, so my CNN input dimension would be:

```
(num_samples,x_dim,y_dim,channels) = (5,10,10,3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the time series dimension is axis 1: `(5, 3, 10, 10, channels)`.

- You can handle time series with recurrent nets (`LSTM`, `GRU`), shape `(batch, steps, channels)`
- You can also use `Conv1D` for time series, shape `(batch, steps, channels)`
- You can handle images with `Conv2D`, shape `(batch, imgX, imgY, channels)`.
- You can mix the two with `Conv2DLSTM`, shape `(batch, steps, X, Y, channels)`.
- You can also mix images and steps is using `TimeDistributed(Conv2D())`, with shape equal to  `(batch, steps, X, Y, channels)`

You must create models that deal with these shapes correctly. The best is to search for some common architectures.